How to resolve GLIBC version issues when running Playwright in AWS Lambda Docker image?
I am trying to create a Docker image that runs a Python script using Playwright on AWS Lambda. I started with the official AWS Lambda Python 3.8 image and added Playwright, but I am encountering GLIBC version issues.
Here's my Dockerfile:
# Start from AWS Python 3.8 base image
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

ENV PIP_ROOT_USER_ACTION=ignore

# Install the dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"
RUN pip3 install playwright==1.45.0 && playwright install --with-deps --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"

# Copy our function code
COPY handler.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
COPY new.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Set the handler function
CMD [ "handler.main" ]

39.69 /var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/playwright/driver/node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/playwright/driver/node)
39.69 /var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/playwright/driver/node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/playwright/driver/node)
------
Dockerfile:9


What Linux distro do you use?

i got this from this thread in playwright github bug report
you are trying to run playwright in linux distro which is not supported by playwright.
you need to check the system requirement section of playwright
supported linux distro by playwright
the version of distro you are trying to use is amazon linux 2 which is not supported by playwright
